# Exiting from a Navigation Controller and going to UIViewController outside Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, swift

that's it, I'm building an app that has a login screen, this login screen is outside the array of a Navigation Controller. Once the login is ok, the user is redirected to a TabBarController that has a Navigation Controller and the user navigates through the screens inside the Navigation Controller.

I need that when the users press the logoff button, they go to the first screen, that is outside the Navigation Controller and TabBarController. How can I do that? Most of the exemples out there talk about "pop" out to the root view controller, that is inside the Navigation Controller stack.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m guessing that the initial presentation from the login ViewController was made with `present`. If yes then all you have to do is:

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Whenever the logout button is pressed. This will present the ViewController over which the TabBarViewController was presented.